# ML error: replacing DARROW with LPAREN

Tags: ml

```
fun make_alt_record (stringlists, {x, y, z}) =
    case generate_alts (stringlists, x) of
    [] => {x, y, z}
      | alt::stringlists' => {name, y, z}
```

generate_alts consumes a string list list and a string, and produces a string list. 
make_alt_record is supposed to generate a new record.

Instead it generates errors, which are as follows:

```
hw2provided.sml:48.6-48.8 Error: syntax error: replacing  DARROW with  LPAREN
hw2provided.sml:49.23-49.25 Error: syntax error: replacing  DARROW with  AS
hw2provided.sml:65.1 Error: syntax error found at EOF
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your record syntax is wrong.  You can pattern match on records, but you can't create them by punning.  You need, e.g.

```
  [] => {x = x, y = y, z = z}
| ... => {x = name, y = y, z = z}
```